# Is there a way to server side render react app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I was using html and css before without using frontend framework but now I use Reactjs and I wanted to know how to server side render pages in this way with html:

```
const app = express();
app.get("/",function(req,res){
 res.render("page");
});
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Next.js**  light weight framework of react, contains  rendering through  server-side / client side pages, create dynamic page ,support server and server less target and webpack ,babel configuration, etc.

https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14953#discussioncomment-34938

Comment: That's very nice.Thanks